# I can not communicate while use wss in the autobahn websocket,why?

Tags: android, ssl, websocket, autobahn

I have a client app on android with autobahn . It is can communicate very well while using ws, but there is some problems when I use wss, the certificate which I use is self signed certificate ,so I make some changes in the class WebSocketConnection.java as the author says.

I use https://github.com/palmerc/SecureWebSockets this project.

---

the error is as follows:
websockets internal error(java.lang.NullPointerException)

---

what I add in the WebSocketConnection.java is as following :

```
 if (mWebSocketURI.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(WSS_URI_SCHEME)) {

    try {
            SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");

            KeyStore trustkeyStore=KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            trustkeyStore.load(MainActivity.activity.getResources().getAssets().open(KEYSTOREPATH_TRUST),
                                                          KEYSTOREPASSWORD.toCharArray());
            sslContext.init(null,trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

            factory=sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem so i found a new awesome library:

> dependency 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996033/4576879) to find more explanation about how to use this lib. WS, WSS, HEADERS are supported with this libraty.