# https://websocket not connect android

Tags: java, android, websocket

I have connect socket `http://(with port)` url is complete and working but I have connect `https://(without port)` not working in Java-WebSocket.

I use gradle dependency  'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'

```
WebSocketClient   mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Websocket: " + "Opened");
        mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() {
        super.connect();
        //Log.e(TAG, "Websocket: " + "connect");
        SharedPreference.storeValue(mContext, SharedPreference.WEB_SOCKET_STATUS, SharedPreference.WEB_SOCKET_CONNECT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your SSL certificate is not signed for your https url.

Comment: To put it simply, the implementation of the WebSocket library has many [open issues](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues) regarding SSL. Its SSL implementation may work under some conditions, but you shouldn't expect it always works.

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution!) If you want to use **wss://** you should set **setWebSocketFactory**.. Just like this:

```
public void connect() {

    final String url = "wss://echo.websocket.org";
    URI uri=null;
    try{
        uri = new URI(url);
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Connected!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Message: "+message);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Disconnected!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error: "+ex.getMessage());

        }
    };

    if (url.indexOf("wss") == 0) {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
            mWebSocketClient.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sslContext));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    mWebSocketClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: How should look something like the file "network-security-config" file and certified? It is required to make the connection

Comment: It is not required. I using it without any "network-security-config" files.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
 </uses-permission>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >  
</uses-permission
```

Please post Log Cat!

Comment: I have add this both permission

Comment: log cat :unkonow scheme  https

Comment: check my answer @Priyanka

Comment: where is your answer ...please can you provide link for solution

Answer (score 0):

Websocket has its own protocols `ws://` or `wss://`(similar to `http://`, `https://`), try to use these protocols.

Comment: I have also try this method but i get exception  malformedurlexception unknown protocol wss

Comment: Your websocket server is running?

Comment: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html
   
this link for online work https to wss but how to integrate in my project url .I also try to replace https to wss in my project but url not work and throw  exception malformedurlexception unknown protocol wss

Comment: try to use this url wss://echo.websocket.org